# How to mapping icons in a new array in React js?

Tags: reactjs, arrays

I have created a new array and I can map other items from that array but I can't map icons. It shows [object Object]

```
import { skillData } from '../../data/pageData';

const allfillteredSkills = [
  'All',
  ...new Set(skillData.map((item) => item.category + item.icon)),
];

console.log(allfillteredSkills);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of `item.icon` and convert it to a string before executing the + operator.

`[object Object]` is what happens when an `object` is formatted to a `string`

here is an example of what happens :

```js
console.log(['All', ...new Set(["categ" + {foo:"bar"}])])
> ['All', 'categ[object Object]']
```

To convert icon to a `string` you have many solution depending on the type of `item.icon`.

If it is an object, you can access a property of it (e.g. `item.icon.name`)

`JSON.stringify(item.icon)` might also work if you want to keep all the informations